# Netty Server Extra EventExecutorGroup for application handler

Tags: java, netty

I'm writing an application server in Java using Netty. I know that long-running tasks should not be executed on the I/O EventLoopGroup threads. Instead, an extra EventExecutorGroup should be assigned to the application handler.

I benchmarked my application and found out that business logic tasks take several hundred microseconds at max. Now I'm wondering whether or not I should really use another thread pool for business logic. Can somebody tell me which order of magnitude "long-running" refers to? Maybe someone has already done benchmarks concerning this decision and can give me some advice regarding this question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to give general advice without looking at a profile. That said if your logic only takes a few microseconds the answer is most likely that you can just run it in the `EventLoop` directly.